# Is it possible to create code snippet with dynamic code in VisualStudio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

i want to create a snippet in visual studio that makes dynamic line of code,for example i want to generate all properties of an object and set value of those to null

```
object.prop1=null;
object.prop2=null;
.
. 
.
```

(my object is dynamic and i want to get its properties with Reflection)

is it posibble? how?

Answer (score 0):

I believe understand what do you want to do.

```
<Literal>
    <ID>objValue</ID>
    <ToolTip>Replace with value for all obj</ToolTip>
    <Default>null</Default>
</Literal>
...
...
class TestClass
{
    var first=$objValue$;
    var last=$objValue$;
    var email=$objValue$;
}
```

When "onValue" is sistituted and tab others is sustituded too.

This is the way that occurs to me.

If not work for you then I suggest you take this other way:

```
setToNull(object Obj)
{
    for(key in Obj)
    {
        Obj[key]=null;
    }
}
```

You have build a method.
Maybe you can find something to help you here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312.aspx
Well, I hope help you. Good Luck.

I love googleTranslate.